# Javascript: Toggle off a function when another function is selected on a SVG

Tags: javascript

I hope someone can help me with the problem I am having. I've got four different paths that each toggle a bolder version when the sign of the destination is clicked. However, I want only one path to be active at a time. I've look all over the web and can't seem to find a solution that works.

So when the "fana" sign is clicked it becomes bold, but when the "landas" sign is clicked, I want the "fana sign" to deselect and go back to its normal state.

Ive added a codepen here, as it is a svg and takes up to many lines for direct input: [codepen.io/Verste/pen/MWpmgQa](https://codepen.io/Verste/pen/MWpmgQa)

JS code:

```
const Fana = document.getElementById("FanaName")
const Landas = document.getElementById("LandasName")
const Laksevag = document.getElementById("LaksevagName")
const Fyllingdalen = document.getElementById("FyllingdalenName")

let clicked = true;

Fana.addEventListener("click", FanaFunction);
Landas.addEventListener("click", LandasFunction);
Laksevag.addEventListener("click", LaksevagFunction);
Fyllingdalen.addEventListener("click", FyllingdalenFunction);

function FanaFunction() {
    if (clicked) {
        document.getElementById("Fana").style.opacity = "0";
        document.getElementById("Fana-H").style.opacity = "1";
        document.getElementById("Fana-H").style.zIndex = "100"
    } else {
      document.getElementById("Fana").style.opacity = "1";
      document.getElementById("Fana-H").style.opacity = "0";
      document.getElementById("Fana-H").style.zIndex = "0"
    } 
} 
function LandasFunction() {
    if (clicked) {
        document.getElementById("Landas").style.opacity = "0";
        document.getElementById("Landas-H").style.opacity = "1";
        document.getElementById("Landas-H").style.zIndex = "100";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("Landas").style.opacity = "1";
      document.getElementById("Landas-H").style.opacity = "0";
      document.getElementById("Landas-H").style.zIndex = "0";
    }
} 
function LaksevagFunction() {
    if (clicked) {
        document.getElementById("Laksevag").style.opacity = "0";
        document.getElementById("Laksevag-H").style.opacity = "1";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("Laksevag").style.opacity = "1";
      document.getElementById("Laksevag-H").style.opacity = "0";
    }
} 
function FyllingdalenFunction() {
    if (clicked) {
        document.getElementById("Fyllingdalen").style.opacity = "0";
        document.getElementById("Fyllingdalen-H").style.opacity = "1";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("Fyllingdalen").style.opacity = "1";
      document.getElementById("Fyllingdalen-H").style.opacity = "0";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your approach was good, but you forgot to toggle the clicked var so it couldn't change...

Can't put the whole snippet in here but the js worked for me like this:

```js
const Fana = document.getElementById("FanaName")
const Landas = document.getElementById("LandasName")
const Laksevag = document.getElementById("LaksevagName")
const Fyllingdalen = document.getElementById("FyllingdalenName")

let clicked = [true, true, true, true];

Fana.addEventListener("click", FanaFunction);
Landas.addEventListener("click", LandasFunction);
Laksevag.addEventListener("click", LaksevagFunction);
Fyllingdalen.addEventListener("click", FyllingdalenFunction);

function FanaFunction() {
    if (clicked[0]) {
        document.getElementById("Fana").style.opacity = "0";
        document.getElementById("Fana-H").style.opacity = "1";
        document.getElementById("Fana-H").style.zIndex = "100";
        clicked[0] = false;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("Fana").style.opacity = "1";
      document.getElementById("Fana-H").style.opacity = "0";
      document.getElementById("Fana-H").style.zIndex = "0";
      clicked[0] = true;
    } 
} 
function LandasFunction() {
    if (clicked[1]) {
        document.getElementById("Landas").style.opacity = "0";
        document.getElementById("Landas-H").style.opacity = "1";
        document.getElementById("Landas-H").style.zIndex = "100";
      clicked[1] = false;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("Landas").style.opacity = "1";
      document.getElementById("Landas-H").style.opacity = "0";
      document.getElementById("Landas-H").style.zIndex = "0";
      clicked[1] = true;
    }
} 
function LaksevagFunction() {
    if (clicked[2]) {
        document.getElementById("Laksevag").style.opacity = "0";
        document.getElementById("Laksevag-H").style.opacity = "1";
      clicked[2] = false;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("Laksevag").style.opacity = "1";
      document.getElementById("Laksevag-H").style.opacity = "0";
      clicked[2] = true;
    }
} 
function FyllingdalenFunction() {
    if (clicked[3]) {
        document.getElementById("Fyllingdalen").style.opacity = "0";
        document.getElementById("Fyllingdalen-H").style.opacity = "1";
      clicked[3] = false;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("Fyllingdalen").style.opacity = "1";
      document.getElementById("Fyllingdalen-H").style.opacity = "0";
      clicked[3] = true;
    }
}
```

Hope this was what you were asking for!

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is over simplified, but I hope that you can see the point.

Instead of assigning an evenlistener to each clickable element I made one for the `g` element that is parent to all the `linje`'s. And in the `if` statement test if a `rect` (or whatever element) was clicked.

Instead of changing specific style properties for each element you can just add or remove a class name. So, now the class name controls how the elements in that particular "linje" should be shown.

```js
var linjer = document.getElementById('linjer');

linjer.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if(e.target.nodeName == 'rect'){
    let linje = e.target.closest('g');
    if(linje){
      // remove all class name "current"
      linjer.querySelectorAll('g.linje').forEach(linje => linje.classList.remove('current'));
      // add class "current" to one
      linje.classList.add('current');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="400" height="400">
  <style>
    g.linje rect {cursor: pointer;}
    g.current line {stroke-width: 20px;}
  </style>
  <g id="linjer">
    <g class="linje" transform="translate(20, 20)">
      <rect width="100" height="50" fill="steelblue"/>
      <line x1="100" y1="25" x2="300" y2="25" stroke="red" stroke-width="10"/>
    </g>
    <g class="linje" transform="translate(20, 100)">
      <rect width="100" height="50" fill="steelblue"/>
      <line x1="100" y1="25" x2="300" y2="25" stroke="red" stroke-width="10"/>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```